# @end must appear in an objective-c context

Tags: objective-c, appearance

I am Following a tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios .

Here is my detailviewcontroller.h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @end <-- //errors shows up here.

    @interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

    @property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
    @end
```

This is my detailview.m  file

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"


@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Detail", @"Detail");
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

As i referred above, the @end error message appears and wait to auto fix in red square, the i agree to do the auto fix. Then the xCode applies the @end code over there, as shown in the .h file. Then an other error appears as which is in the title " @end must appear in an objective-c context "

what should i do ? 
Is xCode gone mad or what.

Whats wrong ?

Comment: Just remove the first `@end` and press Command+B.

Comment: But you know the meaning of "end"?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, somewhere along the line I missed a @end in one of the .h file. So all files that import that .h file is prompting this error. The funny thing is, I don't receive this error message on the one .h file that does miss the @end. So I guess you need to do some searching make sure you close all your @interface, @implementation or @protocol with @end. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove that first `@end`. It's completely wrong. You can only have `@end` after an `@implementation`, `@interface`, or `@protocol` declaration.

Comment: @user1529095: But when you remove it, what?

Comment: yes but when i remove it it asks me to view put it again. Just have a look at this video [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VD4-Zm2Hzbw&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: @user1529095: I think you have something else going on. The fix-it suggestion is just plain wrong.

Comment: I'm getting this weird bug as well.  Did you figure out how to fix?